# Corrupted jar files

Tags: jar

How to identify the corrupted jar files in my classpath using jar commands.

Will -xvf help in sorting out corrupted jars?

Please help.

Comment: I get invalid entry CRC error, so would like to check the jar if had got corrupted, please help..

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need to look at each jar file individually and allow the `jar` command to tell when an archive is corrupt.  You can use the *list* command for this:

```
$ jar tf <jarfile>
```

Alternatively I guess you could just run `java` itself, with your desired classpath, and hope that is declares which jar files are corrupt.

Comment: Okay thank you, i have used list and extract commands, but if it is not able to list, it is not throwing any error. have java.policy in my classpath, it is not a jar file. but when I do tf on it, it takes me back to the cmd prompt without giving any error.

Comment: That's unusual - I would have expected an exception.